# How to use .htaccess to redirect a page but also use it as a W3 include

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building an html site using the include method shown here from w3schools

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

the site basically looks like the following

```
<div w3-include-html="navigation.html"></div>

<body>
</body>

<div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
```

It works great when you're on the right pages of the website but if I navigate directly to navigation.html it displays a terrible looking and useless page.

I tried to redirect it using the .htaccess file with something like the following so a user could gracefully land on a page that says sorry this doesn't exist, click here blah blah...

Redirect /navigation.html /page-not-found.html

however that ends up causing the navigation bar on all my real pages to display the html within the page-does-not-exist.html page.

Is there an easy way to use .htaccess to redirect a user who is directly typing in [www.example.com/navigation.html](http://www.example.com/navigation.html) to [www.example.com/page-not-found.html](http://www.example.com/page-not-found.html) while still allowing my other pages to 'include' it normally?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: The short answer is : `You can't do this` . If you use htaccess to redirect the file then you will end up with the same situation. If you don't want the file to be visible to clients, you can keep it outside the document root folder and include it from there.

Comment: I figured as much!  Thanks....Can you elaborate a little bit or direct me to a page showing how to include from a folder other than the root?  do you mean like above the root on the server or just another folder in general will work? I basically just don't want users to be able to type in www.example.com/navigation.html and see the wonky looking page it produces.

Comment: "how to include from a folder other than the root?" - You can't do that using your current method (JavaScript) - since your script will also be blocked. You can only do that if you are using server-side includes (eg. PHP etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This method uses JavaScript (`XMLHttpRequest` object, ie. "AJAX") to make an HTTP request for the document on the server. Ordinarily, this is no different (from a server perspective) to a direct request that the client might make by typing the URL for the file directly.

You need to make the JavaScript request *different* so it can be detected by the server.

You can add a custom HTTP request header (or override the `User-Agent` string) to the JavaScript request and check for this header using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` on the server to send an alternative response if this header is not set as expected (ie. if the file is requested directly).

For example, based on the code from w3schools, add a second line after creating the `XMLHttpRequest` object:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP');
```

This sets the `User-Agent` header in the JS request to `XMLHTTP`. We can then check for this using mod_rewrite and serve a 404 if not set.

However, you should not "redirect" to the `page-not-found.html` script. Set this as a custom 404 error document instead and allow Apache to serve this.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=XMLHTTP
RewriteRule ^navigation\.html$ - [R=404]
```

Any request for `/navigation.html` where the `User-Agent` string is not `XMLHTTP` is served the custom 404 error document, ie. `/page-not-found.html`. So, only requests from your script are permitted.

NB: This is not a security feature, it simply prevents anyone who casually types the URL into the browser from seeing the content (including search engines).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> <div w3-include-html="navigation.html"></div>
>
> <body>
> </body>
>
> <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
> ```

It looks from this that you are including HTML elements outside of the HTML `body`? This isn't valid HTML.

Comment: awesome write up, I will get to work on trying this.  Thank you so much for the effort you spent posting it.  (from the aside, i meant 'main' not body...just basically the standard navigation, page data, footer layout.     you mentioned 'including search engines'.  Does this mean a spider would end up not being able to crawl the links inside the includes?  it actually seems like it is having that issue in already....maybe thats a story for another day